# What is the value of $0.7\overline{54}+0.69\overline{2}$?

Tags: arithmetic

> What is the value of $0.7\overline{54}$ +$0.69\overline2$?
>
> (a) $\frac{1813}{900}$ (b) $\frac{1783}{910}$ (c) $\frac{14323}{9900} (d) \frac{13243}{9900}$

I get

@edit

$$754-7/990 + 692-69/900$$=$747$/$990$ + $623$/$900$=$1$/$90$($747$/$11$ + $623$/$10$)

=($7470$/$11$ + $623$ . $11$/$10$)=($7470$ + $6853$)=$14323$/$9900$

Thankx for help I did not multiplied by $90$

Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Note that you're quoting the problem wrongly -- it should be $0.7\overline{54}+0.69\overline{2}$, not $0.754+0.692$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $(754-7)/990 + (692-69)/900$?

Comment: It's pretty clear the correct value is between $1$ and $2$. Your value is more than 100.

Comment: How'd you get the denominator to be 110?  The common denominator is 9900.  When you do that you get numerator 14323.  So you get 12323/9900.  It looks like you divided the denominator by 90 but you didn't divide the numerator by 90 (which you can't do anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not $0.754+0.692=?$ 
The question asks $0.7 \overline{54}+0.69\overline2=?$

So the answer will be $0.7 \overline{54}+0.69\overline2=\frac{754-7}{990}+\frac{692-69}{900}=\frac{747}{990}+\frac{623}{900}=1.44\overline{67}=\frac{14323}{9900}$

Comment: $0.7 \overline{54}$ doesn't equal $\frac{754}{990}$ and $0.69\overline2$ doesn't equal $\frac{692}{900}$

Comment: My calculator says $692/900=0.76888\ldots$, not $0.69222\ldots$

Comment: @fleablood I was in the middle of editing when you wrote that. Anyway thanks.

Comment: The OP said s/he did that but got the wrong answer, so apparently, no, the OP can't do the rest.

Comment: @fleablood Fine, I 've solved it totally.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Easier to convert to regular fractions:
$$
0.7\overline{54} = \frac{7}{10} + \frac{54}{99 \cdot 10}
$$
Can you convert the other one?

Answer (score 0):

(754 - 7)/990 + (692 - 69)/900 = 747/990 + 623/900 = 7470/9900 + 6853/9900 = 14323/9900

Answer (score 0):

0.7545454...(+)
0.6922222...[=]
1.44676767...
Now convert this into rational number.
I got the answer as 14323/9900.
Hope this helps.